# derive value of column from other columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
 ----------------
|cloumn1|cloumn2|
-----------------
|   1   |    2  |
-----------------
|   3   |    1  |
-----------------
|   4   |    2  |
-----------------
|   1   |    1  |
-----------------
```

I need a query from my table with this result:

```
 -------------------------------
|cloumn1|cloumn2|compare_result|
--------------------------------
|   1   |    2  |     smaller  |
--------------------------------
|   3   |    1  |     bigger   |
--------------------------------
|   4   |    2  |     bigger   |
--------------------------------
|   1   |    1  |     equal    |
--------------------------------
```

it means if column1 is bigger column 2 the third column(compare_result) shows smaller, if is smaller shows smaller and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column1 > column2 then 'bigger'
             when column1 < column2 then 'smaller'
             when column1 = column2 then 'equal'
             else '???'
        end) as compares_to
from t;
```

You can wrap this logic in a view, so anyone accessing the table can see it.

The `'???'` would occur when one or both of the values are `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` with multiple `WHEN` statements to get the result you need:

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    column2,
    CASE 
        WHEN column1 > column2 THEN 'bigger'
        WHEN column1 < column1 THEN 'smaller'
        ELSE 'equal' 
    END as compare_result
FROM tablename
```

Above query will work if your columns are not nullable (i.e. they cannot be `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query as,

```
SELECT T.*,
   CASE 
    WHEN column1 < column2 THEN 'smaller'
    WHEN column1 > column2 THEN 'bigger'
    WHEN column1 = column2 THEN 'equal'
END AS compare_result
FROM TABLE_NAME T;
```